# Angular UI Route- Changes the url with state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular `ui-router` and defined my routes. But the problem is it changes the state but also changes the url which is not really the intention of using `ui-router`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, need some suggestion on below code

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('ManageUser', {
                url: '/manager-user',
                templateUrl: '/app/user/manage_users.html'
            })
            .state('ManageUserSetting', {
                url: '/user-setting',
                templateUrl: '/app/user/settings_normal.html'
            });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change state without also changing the URL it's as simple as just omitting the `url` parameter from the relevant state:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('ManageUser', {
            url: '/manager-user',
            templateUrl: '/app/user/manage_users.html'
        })
        .state('ManageUserSetting', {
            templateUrl: '/app/user/settings_normal.html' // url is still '/manager-user/'
        });
```

---

That said, in most cases when using `angular-ui-router` you **will** want to change the URL. The main purpose of `angular-ui-router` is to be able to [nest views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) and then be able link directly to those `view states`.

*([Watch this video](http://youtu.be/dqJRoh8MnBo) for an explanation on the differences between `ui-router` and `ngRoute`)*

If in the case which you describe above you merely want to display some user settings inside a nested view, without changing the URL, you might actually be better off using `ng-show` to toggle the settings. The choice is yours.

[Here is an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HnrKcoK0IZdWpdIjgl4r?p=preview) where I've mixed the two. If you'd like a detailed explanation let me know.